# Headers not set on fetch API call

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using the native fetch API, I have this code:

```
fetch('https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/' + surveyId + '/responses/bulk?api_key=' + keySurveyMonkey + '&email=' + customerEmail, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
})
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
```

For some reason the headers are not set, so the API is throwing 401.

Comment: I have tried with and without the credentials: "include"

Comment: When I do the equivalent curl: `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/85596932/responses/bulk?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&email=test@example.com` it works 100%

Comment: Could be a CORS problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662288/setting-authorization-in-native-browser-fetch

Comment: Try to append `mode: 'cors'` object you're passing to `fetch`

Comment: Your "then"-callback syntax is wrong, it should be ***.then(function(response) {...*** see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @Andreas, that's what I thought initially. But, if that was the case, surely the curl would fail as well? Both curl and the app are running from my localhost. I've tried both from my webserver as well.

Comment: @Esko That's the ES6 version of your comment ;)

Comment: @haim770 ... nope, made no difference.

Comment: _“[Could be a CORS problem] But, if that was the case, surely the curl would fail as well?”_ – CORS only affects client-side requests, in the context of a website. Your cURL request is something completely different.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe. So, if that is the case, then my problem is that the SurveyMonkey API does not seem to allow cross origin requests. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that SurveyMonkey recently made some infrastructure changes, that have caused CORS headers not be be sent. I believe this is a temporary situation.